# PDO and special characters

Tags: php, pdo

I have my page encoding set to `utf8` and even in the meta tag as `utf8`.

However, when i'm taking a value from a database it's putting a diamond with a question mark instead - im assuming doesnt know the character.

The character is a é. If i do a echo `é`; it displays as normal on the page. Also if i write it manually in html. However, when i grab the same value from a database call using PDO i get a �

I'm assuming its a PDO setting. I've tried:

```
$db->exec("SET NAMES 'utf8';");
```

but this doesnt resolve it.

Any suggestions?

Comment: what's the charset on the table itself? the entire rendering pipeline has to be the same charset, or at least chained with appropriate conversion logic. e.g. browser->server->php->database->table->database->php->server->browser

Comment: "even meta tag" means for the browser little less than nothing

Comment: If you are on php 5.3.6+, you should set your character set in the dsn string (the first argument of the PDO constructor) like `;charset=utf8`.

Comment: managed to resolve this by adding utf8_encode($variablename) to the variables

Comment: Please do `var_dump(unpack('H*', "é"));` and tell us the output.

Answer (score 2):

Many things can go wrong on the way. Usually you need to have your source file encoded using utf-8, and opening the database connection using utf-8 and defining the database tables as utf-8.

A great article from @deceze that helped me clarify things is http://kunststube.net/frontback/.

The most obvious things you can try in your case are:

1. Save you source file with utf8 encoding. This option exists in editors like Notepad++ or Crimpson Editor.
2. create the PDO connection with utf8 option:

   `$connection = new PDO('mysql:host='.$this->host.';dbname='.$this->db_name.';charset=utf8', $this->user, $this->pass,array(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => false, PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION));`
3. make sure your table is utf-8 encoded and your form has the option :

   < form action="action.php" accept-charset="utf-8">

Update: maybe utf8_encode fixed your problem, but there is a wrong conversion somewhere from the PHP to the database and back. or an wrong file encoding. You should fix the root of the problem, and utf8_encode will not be needed anymore.